# PHP/ HTML login alert box issue

Tags: php, html, authentication, alert

So essentially I have this PHP code which is a login system for a webpage not using MySQL but using pre-determined values within the PHP code. I am running php 5.5.3.

The page I have designed is a called `access.php`. If you enter the pre-defined username and password correctly it takes you through to a `user.php` page, but if either are incorrect it comes up with an alert box: “Incorrect password or username”

However the problem I am having is that when that alert box comes up it fills the same page (`access.php`) with grey and the alert box is located within the middle losing all of the initial web page design, and then when you accept the alert box by pressing 'ok' it takes you back to the `access.php` page design again. I want this alert box to come up over the page I have already designed without losing any of the initial design.

Here is the code for PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    // Set variables to represent data from database
    $dbUsname = "adminDJ";
    $dbPassword = "admin";
    $uid = "1111";

    // Set the posted data from the form into local variables
    $usname = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $paswd = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

    // Check if the username and the password they entered was correct
    if ($usname == $dbUsname && $paswd == $dbPassword) {
        // Set session 
        $_SESSION['username'] = $usname;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $uid;
        // Now direct to users feed
        header("Location: user.php");
    } else {
        print 'incorrect username or password.';
    }   
}
?>
```

Here is the HTML markup:

```
<form id="form" action="access.php" method="post"enctype="multipart/formdata">
  <h2>DJ Access</h2>
  <div class="lineSpacer"></div>
  <p>Username <input type="text" name="username" id="userBox"/></p> <br />
  <p>Password <input type="password" name="password" id="passBox"/></p> <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Login to DJ Access" name="Submit" id="submit"/>
  <div class="lineSpacer"></div>
</form>
```

Is there any way I can have it so PHP either alerts a box within the same page or uses JavaScript to alert a box?

Comment: You should read about ajax.

Comment: This is something I intend to do in the future, but for now I was just wondering if my code was wrong or if there was something I could do to make it work for now.

Comment: Unless you want the box to appear in the access.php-file/page, as @Martin42006 shows in his answer, you'll have to use AJAX to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the above php code is on th esame page access.php then rather than a print set a variable to then use to display a message:

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  $error = false;

  ......

  } else {
    $error = true;
  }
```

then after the form:

```
 <form id="form" action="access.php" method="post"enctype="multipart/formdata">
   <h2>DJ Access</h2>
   <div class="lineSpacer"></div>
   <p>Username <input type="text" name="username" id="userBox"/></p> <br />
   <p>Password <input type="password" name="password" id="passBox"/></p> <br />
   <input type="submit" value="Login to DJ Access" name="Submit" id="submit"/>
   <div class="lineSpacer"></div>
 </form>
 <?php if($error){ ?>
    <div class="error"> There was an issue with the form")</div>
 <?php } ?>
```

or if you want an alert

```
 <?php if($error){ ?>
   <script> alert ("There was an issue with the form")</script>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: This is actually a nicer fix! Thanks :-) - also just out of interest, if you enter the password/ username incorrect the error message comes up... but if you then you enter it correctly and navigate through to the next page (user.php) and then navigate back to access.php the error message is still present; is there a way to remove it once you go back from user.php to access.php?

Comment: Just restart the error message value after the code that checks it `<?php } $error = false; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Just cut out of the php put in the JS and then open the php agsin. Put this where you want the box to appear in the code

```
    ?><script> alert("incorrect details"); window.history.back();</script><?php
```

This should work. :)

Comment: Hi I just tried this, it does the same :-(... it opens up a white page within access.php, alerts me with the incorrect details, then when I accept the 'ok' message it takes it back to the initial page of access.php.

Comment: Hmm it works in safari but not in chrome or firefox... how strange.

Comment: Just tried your updated code but i'm still having the same problem... :/

Comment: To be fair I can deal with it, but it would have been nice to have it in the same page! Thanks for your help though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not seem like it should behave how you are describing it but here is an idea using `setTimeout()`:

**access.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    // Set variables to represent data from database
    $dbUsname = "adminDJ";
    $dbPassword = "admin";
    $uid = "1111";

    // Set the posted data from the form into local variables
    $usname = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $paswd = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

    // Check if the username and the password they entered was correct
    if ($usname == $dbUsname && $paswd == $dbPassword) {
            // Set session 
            $_SESSION['username'] = $usname;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $uid;
            // Now direct to users feed
            header("Location: user.php");
    } else {
            // use a setTimeout to display the alert after 100ms
            print 'setTimeout(function(){alert(\'whatever you want\');}, 100)';
    }   
}
?>

<form id="form" action="access.php" method="post"enctype="multipart/formdata">
<h2>DJ Access</h2>
<div class="lineSpacer"></div>
<p>Username <input type="text" name="username" id="userBox"/></p> <br />
<p>Password <input type="password" name="password" id="passBox"/></p> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Login to DJ Access" name="Submit" id="submit"/>
<div class="lineSpacer"></div>
</form>
```